# What is the purpose of the windows firewall prompt?

Tags: windows, networking, firewall, lan, port

Example:

[image]

What is the purpose of this prompt? Pressing 'Cancel' doesn't block the program from accessing the internet, so... what does accepting this prompt allow the program to do?

I haven't been able to find a straightforward explanation for this online. Some sources say pressing 'Allow access' allows the program to open a port to allow incoming connections (I'm not sure what this would do, as, wouldn't ports for incoming connections have to be handled by port forwarding on the router?). I've also found mentions that this allows the program to access devices on the LAN.

Comment: It makes an explicit rule to allow in the even there was an explicit deny rule. Allow will always override a deny rule.

Comment: @Ramhound So if you cancel it will continue to block it?

Comment: Were you connected on a new public network when the message came up?

Comment: @harrymc This is just an example, the prompt above is just an image I grabbed off google.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default configuration of Windows Firewall is to confirm *inbound* connections only. You get the alert whenever a program tries to create a "listening" socket – most commonly done to accept connections from other machines, but in case of Chrome it's usually for receiving LAN broadcasts for device discovery. (It's either Chrome's built-in UPnP/SSDP support, or mDNS, or both.)

Windows Firewall *could* be configured to prompt for outbound connections, and/or to outright block network access from specific programs (see `wf.msc`), but that's rarely done.

> wouldn't ports for incoming connections have to be handled by port forwarding on the router?

If they actually come from the other side of the router, yes. But that's not always the case – for example, the whole point of Windows having a category for "public" networks is to guard against connections from devices that are already *inside* the network, such as all the various free Wi-Fi networks in stores (many block client-to-client packets, but many do not). In other words, an OS-level firewall is an additional layer on top of the firewall (and the NAT) that the router provides.

Also, not all computers *are* behind a router; when the Windows Firewall interactive prompts were first introduced (in WinXP SP2), it was still extremely common for home Internet connections to be terminated at the computer itself (often because it was still the only LAN-capable device in the household). Your DSL modem would come in 'bridge' mode by default, you would enter PPPoE parameters in Windows, and the computer would directly get a public IP address – the OS firewall would be the *only* defense.

Comment: Good answer! A small addition, note that public IP6 addresses won't be blocked by (IP4) NAT either.

Comment: Right, though they should still be protected by the network's (router's) firewall by default.

Comment: So, in summary, the main purpose of allowing a program to create a listening port nowadays is to allow incoming connections from LAN devices? 

Does this mean any program can create outgoing connections to LAN devices regardless of whether or not this prompt is accepted?

Comment: 1) No, it is not limited to LAN devices. Your BitTorrent client does the same to receive connections from further away. The presence of a router or NAT doesn't change what the program itself needs to do. 2) Yes, just like it can create outgoing connections to the internet. See wf.msc if you want Windows to prompt for outgoing connections.

Comment: 1) Yeah but Bittorrent uses UPnP to do port forwarding from the router. The presence of a router means incoming connections from the internet are blocked from entering the LAN unless a specific port has been forwarded. So, nowadays, where computers are most often behind a router, creating a listening port on the PC only allows incoming connections from LAN devices (unless port forwarding has been set up via the router), correct?